# attributes not selectable by jquery attribute selector

Tags: jquery, css-selectors, css

I am auto generating selectors and ive ran into a problem. some attribute selectors dont work. for example, on [this page](http://dogself.com/telluriumTest/index2.htm) the following selector does not work as expected:

```
$("img[src=/p/aost/logo?logo_id=1238551994]");
```

I also noticed that I cant select a <form> using the value of the action attribute.

**Question:** Is there a full list somewhere of attributes that do not work in jquery selectors.

**Not the question:** I am not asking how to select elements with those attributes using jquery functions.

Thank you.

Answer (score 4):

```
$("img[src='/p/aost/logo?logo_id=1238551994']");
```

Quote the string when you have non-alphanumeric characters, I think you have the same problem in the action url.

Comment: this does not work, at all. for example, in the page above, i have a form with action=list. this selector returns 0 elements: 

$("form[action=list]");