# attributes not found by jquery attribute selector

Tags: jquery, attributes, css-selectors, css

I need to [reask](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/742964/attributes-not-selectable-by-jquery-attribute-selector) my old question, I probably shouldnt have asked it at 1am :P

It seems that some attributes are not being found using jquery's attribute selector:

```
$("*[some=value]");
```

So far it seems that i cant use form's action attribute, and img's src attribute. Is there a list somewhere of attributes that do not work so i can write custom selectors for them?

Thanks again!

---

**Edit:** 
No one seems to believe that some selectors do not work as expected. Look at this example:
On [this site](http://dogself.com/telluriumTest/index2.htm) (which has jquery 1.3 on it for firebugging) there is a form that looks like this:

```
<form style="display: inline;" method="get" action="list">
```

(its around the 'search current downloads' dropdown). If you open firebug and try this selector:

```
$("form[action=list]");
```

you will NOT be able to select the form. There is nothing special about the action attribute. Same goes for the src of the logo image on that page:

```
<img alt="Logo" src="/p/aost/logo?logo_id=1238551994"/>
```

The selector which does not work is:

```
$("img[src=/p/aost/logo?logo_id=1238551994");
```

Sure, i can do wildcard matches, that is not what i am after.

Comment: Please do *not* reask your questions. Simply edit your old one. That will bump it, if you really feel that's useful.

Comment: I did not know that - ill do that in the future

Comment: That's OK, don't worry about it. You might want to edit the old question to link to this one if this question got you a solution, then ask people to vote for closing the old one.

Comment: i already tried deleting it. i cant: This question cannot be deleted - there is at least one answer with up votes

Answer (score 11, accepted):

There is no "list" of unsupported attributes because there shouldn't be; this is a bug in jQuery.

Here are the open tickets on this:

- [Can not select a form using the action attribute](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/3245)
- [attr "action" of form and Selectors' attribute filter](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/2662)
- [selector by attribute "src" not working the same way as in 1.2.6](http://dev.jquery.com/ticket/4244)

Apparently the common denominator between the bugs is that jQuery is comparing the selector string you specify against the full URL as opposed to the actual action/src attribute as it is defined in the HTML. This explains why the [attributeEndsWith](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeEndsWith#attributevalue) or the [attributeContains](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeContains#attributevalue) selectors do work in this case.

I would recommend just giving the form/image a class/ID and getting it over with.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on which jQuery version you're using.

Before 1.3, you could use @ notation:

```
$("*[@name=value]")
```

So maybe adding @ helps.

Other than that, you should enter the attribute value **exactly** the same as it's defined in the markup - e.g. if you're trying to find an image with `src="http://example.com/dog.jpg"`, don't do this because it won't work:

```
$("img[src=dog.jpg")
```

as it will be trying to find images with src **equal** to "dog.jpg", not containing it.

If you want to search attributes defining only parts of it, I'd suggest reading the [jQuery API Selectors](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors) page. For example, to get all images whit src **containing**  "dog.jpg", you could use:

```
$("img[src*=dog.jpg]")
```

Similarly, you can find elements whose attributes start or end with specific values / strings.

Comment: I upgraded my jquery and now the attribute selector (the second example) no longer works. Any thoughts?